# How can i implement sequence section scroll when click only one specific link

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, jquery-plugins

[image]

When user click on this arrow it will go to next section and next click it will go next section. in short sequence section scroll every time user click on down arrow

Here is my HTML

```
<section id="intro">

</section>

<section id="about-us">

</section>

<section id="services">

</section>

<section id="team">

</section>

<section id="contact">

</section>
```

Many thanks in advance

Comment: you can use href jump
http://www.htmlgoodies.com/tutorials/getting_started/article.php/3479511
hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

My example solution (but start always from first element):

```
var ids_arr = [];
$('section').each(function() {
    ids_arr.push(this.id);
});
var tmp_ids_arr = ids_arr;

$('#arrow_element').click(function() {
    if(tmp_ids_arr.length==0) tmp_ids_arr = ids_arr;
    location.hash = '#'+tmp_ids_arr.shift(); // remove first element from collection and returning him
});
```

Comment: WOW it's working fine. just only 2 awkward issue. it's started from very first section and there is no animation when scrolling

Comment: @Nurjaman You didn't mention about animation, yes like i said it start always from top.
If you want start from current section you need update `ids_arr` every time scroll happend. But this is topic for new thread. I solve what you ask in question. If your done accept answer.

Comment: thank you so much buddy :). let's say i wanna start from 'about-us' section then how code will be ? and also is there any way to add smooth scroll instead of jumpy behavior :(